# Setup shortcut keys not working

Tags: shortcut-keys

In my Ubuntu 12.04, in keyboard settings, I didn't find a shortcut for restarting X, so in "Custom Shortcut", I set up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> for the command `sudo restart lightdm`. But the shortcut doesn't work. Is it because it requires root privilege?

Also I have a SysRq key on my keyboard, which I think is the "Magic SysReq Key". My SysRq key is shared with <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key (for screen shot), and is in blue which means I have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> key at the same time to invoke SysRq instead of <kbd>PrtSC</kbd>.

But every time I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd>, it always produces a screenshot, just as when I hit <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> without hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd>. I wonder how to use the Magic SysReq Key? Does it mean the shortcut has not been linked to any command that is defined for Magic SysReq Key yet?

PS: My laptop is Lenovo T400 and OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for the 1st question.**

In order to restart your X server with "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>",

1. Open "System Setting > Keyboard Layout".
2. On Keyboard Layout, click the **option** button in bottom right corner.
3. Expand “Key Squence to kill the X server” and then check "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>"

[image]

**Answer for the 2nd question.**

Magic SysRq keys active by default in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

You can check to execute this command:

```
sudo cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

Then, you can see "1" in terminal, this means "enable all functions of sysrq".

To perform a safe reboot, use  REISUB SysRq Magic combination key:

**Hold** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> then type **R+E+I+S+U+B** , you need to press each key for 2-3 seconds.

**Caution:** Don't release <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd>, when you type R+E+I+S+U+B. And, after you type "E", black screen comes out. But you have to continue typing "I+S+U+B".

So, you can reboot your PC safely.

Safely shutting down Ubuntu when it is frozen, use "R+S+E+I+U+O" keys instead of "R+E+I+S+U+B".

**Meaning of each keys:**

- **B**: Will immediately reboot the system without syncing or unmounting your disks.
- **O**: Will shut your system off (if configured and supported).
- **R**: Will switch the keyboard from raw mode, the mode used by programs.
- **S**: Will attempt to sync all mounted filesystems.
- **U**: Will attempt to remount all mounted filesystems read-only.
- **P**: Will dump the current registers and flags to your console.
- **T**: Will dump a list of current tasks and their information to your console.
- **M**: Will dump current memory info to your console.
- **E**: Send a SIGTERM to all processes, except for init.
- **I**: Send a SIGKILL to all processes, except for init.
- **L**: Shows a stack backtrace for all active CPUs.

I think that you may arrange the combination of these keys (after considering the meaning of the keys) , since this is an example.

You can reboot system using only B command key, or shutdown using only O command key. But, especially , it may be important to remount a file system safely by "read-only" using U key, to protect that a file breaks in the case of forced termination.

Comment: Thanks! (1) I wonder what differences are between the purposes of "R+S+E+I+U+O" and of "R+E+I+S+U+B"? (2) Can I just use part of the commands, such as just "R+S", or "R", without using "R+S+E+I+U+O" or "R+E+I+S+U+B"?

Comment: Thanks! (1) Why it is important to remount a file system safely using U key, given that the system is shutting down? (2) Why "Safely shutting down Ubuntu when it is frozen, use "R+S+E+I+U+O" keys instead of "R+E+I+S+U+B""?

Comment: (1) Why is it not good that "the important files will be rewritten"? Isn't it good to save any unsaved work, so we won't risk losing our previous work? (2) So the difference between "R+E+I+S+U+B" and "R+S+E+I+U+O"  is the former reboot the OS and the latter shut down the OS?

Comment: If the earlier S has already saved all unsaved work, who will rewrite important files, which must be avoided by using U after S?

Comment: It means as protecting that a file breaks in the case of forced termination. It seems that there are too many comments...

Comment: I added the summary of the eliminated comments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `gksudo` instead of `sudo` , because your are in graphic interface, so you can type the password.
2. Here you can see something about SysRq: [Link](http://linuxaria.com/howto/sysrq-linux-ubuntu?lang=en)